# Blocked in work with VS 2022 .NET Core 6: "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.DataAI.NuGetRecommender.Contracts"

Tags: visual-studio, nuget-package, package-managers

I can not use NuGet Package Manager because in the package browse window I got the Error occurred message. Clicking "Show errors in output" gives:

> Could not load file or assembly
> 'Microsoft.data.NuGetRecommender.Contracts, Version=2.1.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
> dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Using the latest 17.0.1 version.

- No google searches give valuable results.
- As a workaround can I somehow turn off NuGet recommendations?

[image]

Comment: I fat-fingered the bounty. I meant to say 17.0.2 and it appears I can't edit it

Answer (score 15):

I was getting the exact same error having all of my extensions disabled.

I turned back on the one called "NuGetRecommender" and it worked perfectly!  Hope that helps

[image]

Comment: I had NugetRecommender disabled, I enabled it ant the problem is gone

Answer (score 5):

You can try to **disable** or reinstall (although it seems it also has [some issues](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/cannot-uninstall-nugetrecommender-extension/1567753) currently) the **NugetRecommender extension**:

[image]

The missing file should be in extension directory:

```
c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\NuGetRecommender\
```

[image]

You can try to download the nuget package and copy the missing dll there.

Comment: Many thx. Unfortunately the issue is not that simple. 1) Already at the time of writing OP the recommender extension was *disabled*, VS still wanted to load the assembly, even after machine reboot. 2) The issue is not deterministic, sometimes it works, sometime it does not, I can not figure out any causabilty so far. Exiting VS or even reboot does not helps, that is confirmed.

Comment: I had NugetRecommender disabled, I enabled it ant the problem is gone

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is still a problem. But I had the same issue and restoring Nuget Packages is what helped make it go away very easily.
In VS 2022, and a lot of earlier versions, right click on the solution and use the context menu to restore the NuGet packages.

Answer (score 0):

In developercommunity.visualstudio.com ticket https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Removing-NugetRecommender-extension-brea/10019083?q=NugetRecommender it was claimed that this is **fixed in Visual Studio 17.3** (2022).

However this very similar issue is still open:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/NuGet-Package-Manager-fails-to-browse-pa/1625135?q=NugetRecommender

(Personally I have 17.3 and it is indeed still a problem).